# How to upload a big file from a form to Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an HTML form with a file field that is used to upload a file to a `/file` route in my Phoenix application.

I mimic this behaviour from command line with `curl -v -F "file=@MyTestFile"  http://localhost:4000/file/` for faster testing.

When I use a big file (turning point seems to be around 7.7MB), I get the following exception from Plug:

> 18:40:38.897 [error] Error in process <0.420.0> with exit value: {[{reason,#{'**exception**'=>true,'**struct**'=>'Elixir.Plug.Parsers.RequestTooLargeError',message=>nil}},{mfa,{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler',init,3}},{stacktrace,[{'Elixir.Plug.Parsers',reduce,6,[{file,"lib/plug...

Is there a workaround to allow bigger files to be uploaded?

There seems to be a `:length` option keyword in Plug, but how could I set it from Phoenix? And what is the reason this particular value of `8_000_000` has been chosen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure this in your `config/config.exs` file:

```
config :phoenix, MyApp.Router,
  ...
  parsers: [parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
            accept: ["*/*"],
            json_decoder: Poison,
            length: 100_000_000],
```

Comment: It seems to require a version >=0.5.0 though, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. 0.6.0 is just out as well, so I would recommend upgrading to the latest/greatest if you're able. You can follow the upgrade guides here https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/e774e6ab5220e6505a03 as well as ping me on #elixir-lang irc if you have issues.

Comment: I can't get this working for Phoenix 0.13.1. I modified [config/config.exs](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/imageyard/blob/0eaf0fe2954bf04064576935b1f43e8f978b1d85/config/config.exs). Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: you now pass these options explicit to the `plug Plug.Static, ..` in endpoint.ex.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, for the most up-to-date docs on this functionality (since this question and these answers are pretty out-of-date at this point), see the official docs at: https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/file-uploads

Comment: PAGE NOT FOUND as of now

Answer (score 1):

Note that the accepted answer means that all request types will increase their maximum allowed lengths. As of Feb 2022, the [`Plug.Parsers` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/1.13.3/Plug.Parsers.html#module-examples) show that you can set this just for the multipart parser in your `endpoint.ex` as:

> If you want to increase the limit only for multipart requests (which is typically the ones used for file uploads), you can do:

```
plug Plug.Parsers,
     parsers: [
       :url_encoded,
       {:multipart, length: 20_000_000}, # Increase to 20MB max upload
       :json
     ]
```