# Elixir: how to post image to api

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using erlang's httpc in elixir like 
  `:httpc.request(:post, {url, headers, content_type, body},[],[])` within a phoenix app to try and post an image to an api, so far i am creating the body like

`{:ok, data} = File.read(image.path)
body = "{ \"param\": \"value\", \"file\": #{data}}"` I am not sure where i am going wrong but the request works with out the file param

My question is what is the elixir way of doing this?

Comment: You could try to use [HTTPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison), which may be more Elixir-y. Specifically, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134219/how-to-upload-a-big-file-from-a-form-to-phoenix

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I eventually went with erlcloud to upload to S3 which was super easy

Comment: @AbeyOnalaja please post an answer that describes how you got his working for future Googlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above I used [erlcloud](https://github.com/gleber/erlcloud) to upload to AWS
make sure to export your AWS Keys as per the getting started
In phoenix mix.exs deps add

{:erlcloud, github: "gleber/erlcloud"}

sample code

`def create(conn, params) do
    image = params["image"]
    image_url   = to_char_list(image.filename})
    {:ok, data} = File.read(image.path)
    :ssl.start()
    :erlcloud.start()
    :erlcloud_s3.put_object(__FOLDER__, image_url, file,[],[])
end`

Comment: In the function call, shouldnt it be data, instead of file?